# Why do some pros play in 4:3?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

When i see footage from some CS:GO lan event i notice that a lot of the professional players play in 4:3 on a 16:9 screen with black bars on the sides.

Why do they prefer 4:3 over 16:9? Is there any advantage here?

Comment: Your FOV is actually less. I believe it's mostly due to familiarity.

Comment: don't downvote this, this is a good question

Comment: Gamers have a lot of non-sensical beliefs.  See: refusing to play with wireless controllers; turning off v-sync; claiming a 5ms difference in ping makes a huge difference; demanding 120+ fps with a 60hz screen; [disabling interp](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Entity_interpolation); etc.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Wireless controllers have batteries that die regularly, 5ms can easily be the difference between who acts first in any reaction-dependent game, and v-sync caps FPS to 60 in many games (and I can absolutely tell the difference between 60 and 100 FPS, regardless of the hz of the screen.), and the difference between an interp of .1 and 0 or .01 is monstrous in fast paced shooters.

Comment: @Decency: A 60fps game, or a 60-tic server *(which is **all** source-servers, regardless of what they claim)*, only processes input once every 16.6ms, so a 5ms difference will in all likelihood result in **literally** no difference. Also, there is no physical difference between 60fps and 120fps on a 60hz monitor; the extra frames are simply dropped.  And setting interp to 0 actually makes the client *less* accurate *(you'd have to lead moving targets to hit them)*. The fact that gamers don't notice only goes to show that these issues are mostly psychological.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You can see the tic of the server with console settings for net_graph. No idea about CS:S, but CS:GO public servers are 64 tic, and most serious private servers are 128 tic. No idea regarding the hz, but if I'm on fps_max 60 in Counter-Strike, I notice a round or two. interp 0 is a sentinel that causes the delay to be dynamic based on updaterate: which is almost always lower if configured properly. Regardless, you never have to 'lead moving targets', that's the whole point of the interpolation. Lower values are mandated by leagues for precision.

Comment: The tickrate of all source-engine games *(including CS:GO)* [is fixed in the code](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#Optimizations).  Contrary to popular belief, changing the `tickrate` cvar does not actually do anything.  There is no such thing as a 128-tic CS:GO server, despite widespread claims to the contrary by server-rental companies.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Seeing as that section hasn't been modified since 2012, and the vast amount of evidence to the contrary (most blatant example: doors close twice as fast after being opened on 128tic) you're going to have to do quite a bit better than that to prove that it's unmodifiable in CS:GO.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft BTW (I know this is from 3 years ago), V-Sync adds a noticeable lag, along with wireless controllers which are not designed to minimize input lag (AFAIK some new wireless gaming mice and XBox One controllers are designed to minimize input lag).  V-Sync can be quite a substantial lag added on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some people claim it offers a better field of view or gives you an advantage. But mostly it's just down to **personal preference**. In some cases, players may prefer playing in 4:3 because that's how they played **earlier iterations of the Counter-Strike series** (such as 1.6).

FOV is not bigger, though. As noted by Decency in their comment, 16:9 offers you a wider FOV, the full 90 degrees, while 4:3 gives a FOV of ~74 degrees.

Comment: "Claim" it offers a better FOV? Surely that's easily testable.

Comment: @kotekzot 16:9 offers you a wider FOV, the full 90 degrees. 4:3 gives a FOV of ~74 degrees.

Comment: Seems weird that they would handicap themselves just because they are used to it... Old habits die hard i guess.

Comment: @b00n - There might *some* advantages, such as only having to watch a smaller portion of the screen, and not having as far to move the crosshair to reach someone at the edge of the screen, but I don't think it's worth the loss of vision.

Comment: @Stark You maybe don't have to move your crosshair, but the enemies are still there :D

Comment: @lub - Exactly, that's why I don't understand how people think it's a benefit

Comment: Advantages are not merely a positive.  You actually have to adapt to said advantage.  Adaptation is not an instantaneous process and the time investment may not be worth it for some.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro but..

I've played 4:3 because the models are bigger and you're less likely to miss.
However, it's a minor difference and as Stark already noticed, it comes down to personal preference.

I've had some games where I didn't see an enemy because of my 4:3 ratio, but my teammates who played CS:GO in 16:9 did.